# Modal input not scrolling to input field on focus when mobile keyboard pops up in angular 5

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I've bootstrap modal in angular 5 application with the fixed position property along with top, right,  bottom & left properties set to 0 for mobile devices.

The **problem is in mobile devices** when user clicks on text input field in the **modal mobile keyboard pops up** but input gets hidden behind the keyboard. I want to make input element **scroll up**, so that user can see what he/she is typing. Can anybody provide any idea to achieve this i'll appreciate if any suggestions.

I've tried by giving template reference to input element and tried to scroll element on focus event by manually setting scroll on the input element

Comment: Please post code.